# InsufficientBalanceException("Insufficient spendable states identified for $requiredAmount.")

Tags: blockchain, corda

I am getting the below CordaRunTime Exception

```
InsufficientBalanceException: Insufficient spendable states identified for $requiredAmount.
```

when i tried to execute a transaction by transferring  "100"  tokens from one Account(sender) to  Account (receiver). But i didn't issue any tokens to the sender Account.
I understand that if we tried to transfer the tokens when there is no tokens available in vault to transfer it was throwing this exception.

The exception is fine (as per [corda](https://docs.r3.com/en/api-ref/corda/4.8/open-source/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.contracts/-insufficient-balance-exception/index.html) it will throw InsufficientBalanceException when They're not enough tokens in the vault to transfer,
**but I want to understand when its throwing this exception the execution of transaction is taking more time 10 seconds(aproxx) than usual. if we have sufficient tokens to transfer its taking only 800 ms. **

What are the reasons , **why corda is taking more time to execute a transaction when its throwing this exception: InsufficientBalanceException.**

Thanks in Advance.

Test Scenario that i have tried:

1. I have not issued the tokens to Account(sender) but i tried to execute a transaction which is transferring the 100 tokens from one Account (sender) to another Account(receiver). Iam getting the CordaRuntimeException:

```
InsufficientBalanceException: Insufficient spendable states identified for $requiredAmount.
```

by throwing this exception its completing the execution of the transaction Flow. But its taking more time approximately 10 Seconds than an successful transaction (means a successful transaction by transferring the tokens). For successful transaction it is taking only 1 Sec.

but I want to understand when its throwing this exception the transaction taking more time (10 seconds) to complete. What are the reasons , **why corda is taking more time to execute a transaction when its throwing this exception: InsufficientBalanceException**.

Answer (score 0):

if you look into the code of the TokenSelection model, you will see that a retry mechanism is in place. Hence by default it tries for 8 times before confirming that it doesn't have enough balance. Take a look [here](https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/blob/301ac85f330442e71b4cce9469f1861181d37573/modules/selection/src/main/kotlin/com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.selection/database/selector/DatabaseTokenSelection.kt#L144).

This [maxRetries](https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/blob/301ac85f330442e71b4cce9469f1861181d37573/modules/selection/src/main/kotlin/com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.selection/database/config/DatabaseSelectionConfig.kt) field is configurable, you can add it to a config file.